# Is there a sexier way to write this jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select all the children of the `body` element before element with id `foo` (which is a child of `body`). Since it doesn't look like there are `:before()` or `:after()` selectors, I've got it working like this:

```
$('body > :first').nextUntil('#foo').andSelf();
```

but it seems kludgy. Could this be done with fewer function calls, or more efficiently? Maybe something akin to `$('body > *:before(#foo)')` ?

Comment: Actually, there is an after selector named Next Siblings Selector `$('#foo ~ *')`  However, I don't see a before.  It may still be better to use nextUntil because * tends to be a performance problem.

Comment: So maybe I could get what I want by negating that. Maybe more elegant, probably slow.

Comment: `$('body >  *:not(#foo, #foo ~ *)');` takes about 750 times longer than `$('body').children().first().nextUntil('#foo').andSelf()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that kludgy. Infact, using your example with "*" within the selector is WAY slower than calling functions.

So, I would suggest using one function more in your original selector:

```
$('body').children().first().nextUntil('#foo').andSelf()
```

most of those functions use a simple array slice to reduce the set, where selecters
have to traverse the DOM.

Comment: `first()` returns the first element of the matched set (like using `$($('body')[0])`), not the first child.

Comment: ...so it would have to be `$('body').children().first().nextUntil('#foo').andSelf()`

Comment: *Any* selector using the non-standard jQuery-only selectors will be slow compared to standard CSS selectors like `body`. This is because standard selectors can be passed off to the fast native `querySelectorAll` method in modern browsers. Always use the method version (like `first()`) in preference to the selector version unless you really have no other choice.

Comment: jAndy - I modified your answer so that it actually works, as per my earlier comment.